Designing a variable negative output voltage converter with low ripple
I want to design a variable output regulator to convert 12V to -10V to 0V @1.5A.

My idea is to convert 12V to -10V  using an LTC7149:

I have 40mV ripple at 1.5A. I need to reduce this ripple as much as possible so I decided to add a  variable output LDO to reduce the ripple. Is my approach correct? Would you please let me know if there is a better way of doing this?


It looks like you have 20mohm ESR on the output capacitors. With ceramics that should be lower. Otherwise a higher inductance could also be away to go.

Have you tried post filtering? Have you tried lower ESR capacitors?

Post-regulation with a linear regulator is common practice, for the reasons you have discovered for yourself. It's not as simple as throwing on an LDO regulator, though, because they are typically bad at attenuating high frequency ripple, especially when that ripple is in the tens of kilohertz or more.
In your block diagram, you show the DC-DC converter output as -10V, which would be insufficient to obtain -10V from any linear regulator. Regulator input voltage will necessarily have to exceed -10V, say -11V for an LDO type regulator, to comply with its minimum drop-out voltage. The ideas I suggest below will require even more still, maybe -12V.
A simple RC filter with a cut-off frequency well below the switching frequency of the DC-DC converter could work well, if you can keep the capacitance small compared to the output capacitance of the switcher. Your design uses 22μF output capacitance, and seems to be switching at 1MHz.
Whatever resistance \$R\$ you use must not develop any significant DC voltage at a full load of 1.5A. Guessing that a 0.5V drop would be tolerable:
$$ R = \frac{0.5V}{1.5A} = 330m\Omega $$
If we choose a cut-off frequency of 100kHz, well below the 1MHz ripple:
$$ C = \frac{1}{2\pi fR} = \frac{1}{2\pi \times 100kHz \times 330m\Omega} \approx 4.7\mu F $$
That's quite a small compared to 22μF, so it's worth a try:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Input \$V_{IN}\$ is about 12V DC, with a triangular ripple 40mV pk-pk:

Potential \$V_A\$ at A looks like this, with just over 3mV pk-pk:

Note that R1 is passing 1.5A with 0.5V across it, dissipating \$0.5V \times 1.5A = 0.75W\$ of power. Use a reasonably beefy resistor, 1W or more. C1 should also be low ESR; you could also place a ceramic 100nF capacitor in parallel with it to obtain best high-frequency attenuation.
It's much better, but perhaps we can improve even more, with a capacitance multiplier:

simulate this circuit
It looks a little different from the usual positive-supply ones, because it employs a PNP transistor Q1 instead of NPN. Q1 is an emitter follower. Its base is presented with heavily low-pass filtered (by R1 and C1) version of input \$V_{IN}\$, missing most of the 1MHz ripple. The emitter follows the base, albeit 0.7V or so lower, also relatively noise free:

With ideal layout and components, this shows less than a millivolt of 1MHz ripple.
Cut-off frequency is \$f=\frac{1}{2\pi R_1C_1}=16kHz\$, much lower than the simple RC filter, and therefore much more effective at removing 1MHz ripple. The magic is that it is achieved with only 1μF of capacitance, which should be ceramic for best results.
Beware power dissipation in Q1, though, due to the 0.7V across it: \$P=0.7V\times 1.5A=1.1W\$. It will have to be a medium-power device.

thanks for the great answer, I tried to simulate the emitter follower in LTspice, but it seems there is around 900 mV. I do not know what I did i wrong. there is a load (6.6 Ohm) connected to the emitter and GND, the output voltage is 9V, making 1.3A.

for the simple RC filter is there any dependency on the load? I mean dependency of quality of ripple rejection on different loads?

@Andromeda In the follower/capacitance multiplier design, R1 isn't some arbitrary resistance, you must consider maximum collector (load) current, and transistor $\beta$. Remember that R1 must provide sufficient base current for the required collector current. 900mV doesn't sound like much to me, but if it's a problem, perhaps R1 is too large, and throttling the transistor.


is my approach correct?

Yes, as long as the LDO has enough ripple rejection at the frequencies of interest - 1MHz and harmonics.

if there is a better way of doing this?

You can increase the switcher's inductor, as long as the duty cycle remains within what the switcher chip can handle.
It is also possible to make the LDOs job easier by adding a stage or two of a passive LC "pi" filter between the output capacitor of the switcher, and the input capacitor of the LDO.
It is important to keep those filters damped, with Q not much higher than 1. That may mean adding small series resistors to the filter. You'll have to simulate that, using models of inductors and capacitors downloaded from their manufacturer. The default "ideal+ESR" models don't capture the performance of real parts all too well for this application.
The filters should be evaluated not only for ripple suppression, but also for step response as-if the load was connected, then disconnected.
With filters in place, the LDO input capacitor should be sized as-if the LDO was "far away" from the voltage source, since the filters add impedance where the LDO needs it to be low.

The output current of this switcher is the inductor current when the bottom FET is on, and zero when the bottom FET is off. So, output current will look like a rectangle wave with sloped tops. To simplify, let's say it flips between 0 and IL.
Increasing the inductance on the switcher will make the top of the current pulses less sloped, but it won't change the fact output current comes in pulses. That's a given with this topology. So it won't do anything for your problem.
Due to this chopped output current, output voltage will ripple at the switching frequency due to output cap ESR and impedance. A solution can be to simply add more low-ESR capacitance (ie, ceramics) but watch out for stability, as these caps are in the feedback loop.
You can also add a CLC filter at the output, suitably sized to be is effective at the switching frequency.
The CLC filter is outside of the switcher's feedback loop, so it will increase output impedance. It should be well damped. If it rings, it can make the problem worse.
There's a compromise, as you want the switching frequency to be high to shrink the filter inductor, but LDO PSRR falls with frequency. In any case, make sure you pick a LDO with strong PSRR.
In addition, when the MOSFET switches, output current di/dt is very high. Combined with the inductance of the output cap, this creates a voltage spike on the output due to \$ e=L \frac{di}{dt}\$. This is not present in your simulation because the output cap's inductance is set to zero.
The spectrum of these spikes is very spread out to high frequency (100M-GHz) so there is no chance to get rid of them with a LDO, as its PSRR only works well at much lower frequencies. So you need low inductance caps, ie several in parallel, with a low inductance layout, ground plane and plenty of vias.
You may need two CLC filters in series, or two inductors in series. This is because higher value inductors have more turns, thus more inter winding capacitance. So a higher value inductor that works well to get rid of the switching frequency ripple is going to suck at filtering out the spikes... and a high frequency ferrite bead, being a single turn inductor, has very low capacitance and will work well against the spikes, but its inductance will be too low to filter the switching ripple.
Care should be taken to avoid saturation.
If you really want "as low ripple as possible"... then another solution is to use a DC-DC topology that produces less ripple to begin with. For example a multi-phase DC-DC, or something based on a transformer, but not flyback. If the output current is less chopped, then there will be less ripple on the output.

The other answers are explaining the issues you are having with noise, notably that the output of your converter has discontinuous current.
You should instead use a Cuk converter -- it inverts, can boost or buck (whilst inverting), and has continuous input and output current.  If you use a coupled inductor, which isn't necessary, you can get input or output current ripple to hit zero for a certain line/load by precisely controlling the coupling factor.
There's ample ICs that can drive it and reference designs.  I've used them before for a negative PSU for hi-fi audio applications. Follow the Cuk by a CLC filter and an LDO and it's effectively silent.  Possibly, you don't even need the post-filtering.
